# Livedata has different values in different activities

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm using Android MVVM in my kotlin app. I have a `UserViewModel` class which has all the user related data the app requires to function.

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val currentUid = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var currentUser = MutableLiveData<User>()
    // More code here...
}
```

The `currentUser` is fetched from firestore at launch and is made available to all the activities. I want to access the `currentPlan` object inside `User`. I do this:

```
someFunc(userViewModel.value!!.currentPlan!!)
```

This is works fine in my `HomeFragment` inside my `MainActivity`. The `HomeFragment` has a message button which takes user to `ChatActivty`.

The problem is when I execute the same function call in `ChatActivity` I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.**, PID: 30420
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.makeshaadi/com.makeshaadi.ChatActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.makeshaadi.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.kt:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30420 SIG: 9
```

Why does `userVM.value` becomes null in `ChatActivity`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a different instance of the ViewModel in your ChatActivity. ViewModels are not singletons

Comment: Woah! How do I fix this? I declare them like this: `private val userVM: UserViewModel by viewModels()` @tyczj

Comment: Long story short is you are expecting the ViewModel to be a singleton when they are not, they are created for each activity. You can create some sort of "UserService" class that acts like a singleton and you pass this class to your view model. You might want to look into using `Dependency Injection`

Comment: Use multiple Fragments in a single Activity instead of multiple Activities. Use `by activityViewModels()` in the Fragment, and the different Fragments will get the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Some theory

There are multiple ways to create instance of a `ViewModel` class (maybe I missed some):

```
// #1 lazy loaded class level variable. 
// Activity serves as view model store
val vm: UserViewModel by activityViewModels()

// #2 lazy loaded class level variable. 
// Activity or Fragment serves as a view model store owner.
// Depends on from which class it is used.
val vm: UserViewModel by viewModels()

// #3 A variable defined in a function scope. 
// `this` is either Activity or a Fragment. The same as #2 but not lazy.
val vm = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)

// #4 The same as the third option but with factory parameter. 
// Used in cases when view model constructor accepts custom arguments.
// Factory takes care of passing correct parameters.
val vm = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
```

What is common is that you always implicitly or explicitly use **view model store owner**. It is either an Activity or a Fragment. View models live as long as the view model store lives. It is constrained by Activity/Fragment lifecycle. When Fragment is destroyed all view models created by that fragment will also be destroyed (if there are circular references). The same goes for the Activity.

This is also how [shared view models](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) are created. Fragments can re-use the same view model **as long as it is owned by the Activity**. This is why we have two lazy loading functions: `by activityViewModels()` and `by viewModels()`. The first one primarily used for shared view models.

#### How to fix the issue?

Either do not use a view model and create a singleton `object` or use a singleton view model (highly do not recommend).

If your application shares some data during its lifecycle and you are sure this data should be stored and accessed from a single place - singleton will help.

This is like having a connection to a database. Usually, there is only one open connection or it is opened and closed by request but I haven't seen latter implementation with databases, usually with files.

I suggest using Kotlin's `object`s:

```
object MySingleton {
    val currentUid = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var currentUser = MutableLiveData<User>()
    // More code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
Create class `UserRepository` and inject singleton `UserRepository` (manually, or Dagger, Koin, ..)

Comment: It will not help when used in different activities.

Comment: Updated answer .

Comment: This is indeed an option!