# Android: Clear DialogFragment ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am creating a dialog extending `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Inside this dialog I have a ViewModel to hold the state of the fragment (it has some inputs inside).  Some of the properties of the ViewModel are `LiveData`. I've noticed that when dismissing the dialog (either calling `dismiss()` or tapping outside the dialog) and reopening it, the values of the `LiveData` properties persist.

So as a solution, I thought to override the `onDismiss()` event to manually clear the data inside the ViewModel:

```
 override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
//        Clear the viewmodel
        viewModel.clear()
        viewModelStore.clear()

        super.onDismiss(dialog)
//        Unsubscribe from observer
        viewModel.getContact().removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)

    }
```

`viewModel.clear()` is a function in my ViewModel that resets the data inside to default values.

Apparently, this wasn't enough either, since even after resetting the data inside the ViewModel before the dismissal, when reopening the dialog, the ViewModel hold the data that it held before calling `clear()`

Since the properties that are not `LiveData` do reset, I believe there is a specific way of reseting `LiveData` value, but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me out?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code that instantiates your `viewModel` variable. This most likely the place to look. This is a bit similar to the question I've answered yesterday. This answer could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63564575/7210237

Comment: I instantiated the viewmodel using by viewModels

Comment: I see you are commenting on both of my active questions. Would you like to move to chat? That should speed things up

Comment: No problem. Try @Snehil answer first. Maybe it will help.

Comment: No luck unfortunately.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu come over chat.stackoverflow.com if you would like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Adrian kindly provided me with a sample of his project. This answer is based on the results of debugging the sample project.*

The problem causing the issue you have is actually located in your `MainActivity` class. You instantiate `AddReminderFragment` in `onCreate` method of your activity and when [FAB](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button) is pressed you display the instance of this fragment.

Everything seems good, except - **you always present the same instance of `AddReminderFragment`**. It means when you present this fragment for the first time you get brand new `AddReminderViewModel` that is lazy loaded using `by viewModels()`.

Initially, I thought the lazy loading `by viewModels()` was causing this issue because it uses the fragment itself as the view model store and **it caches created view model** in case you will want to reuse it later. It was not the case.

#### How to fix the issue?

**Never store references to activities and fragments** or avoid as much as you can and be careful when you have any. It can potentially lead to a memory leak.

Shortly described what I did:

1. Removed `private lateinit var modal: AddReminderFragment` variable from `MainActivity`;
2. Removed `ITimePipupCallback` from `MainActivity`;
3. Removed `onAttach(context: Context)` from `TimePopupFragment`;
4. Implemented `fun setCallback(callback: ITimePipupCallback): TimePopupFragment` in `TimePopupFragment`;
5. Before showing an instance of `TimePopupFragment` from `AddReminderFragment` passed in a callback `ITimePipupCallback` instance. As if it was a callback to a button click of an `AlertDialog`;
6. Removed `onTimePicked` and `onDayPicked` methods from `AddReminderFragment` as they are no longer needed.

Updated `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val AddReminderModalTag = "add_reminder_modal"
    }

    private lateinit var binding: MainActivityBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.showModalHandler = this
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    fun showAddReminderModal(view: View) {
        AddReminderFragment.newInstance().show(supportFragmentManager, AddReminderModalTag)
    }
}
```

Updates made to the `AddReminderFragment`:

```
class AddReminderFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    ...
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        ...
        
        //Bind the add time button
        binding.addTimeButton.setOnClickListener {
            TimePopupFragment
                .newInstance(viewModel.getReminderType().value!!)
                .setCallback(object : ITimePipupCallback {
                    override fun onTimePicked(hour: Int, minute: Int) {
                        viewModel.addTimeToRemind(hour, minute)
                    }

                    override fun onDayPicked(day: Int) {
                        viewModel.addTimeToRemind(day)
                    }
                })
                .show(
                    parentFragmentManager,
                    TIME_PICKER_TAG
                )
        }

        ...

        return binding.root
    }

    ...
}
```

Updates made to `TimePopupFragment`:

```
class TimePopupFragment : DialogFragment() {
    ...
    private lateinit var callback: ITimePipupCallback
    
    // Removed `onAttach` method
    fun setCallback(callback: ITimePipupCallback): TimePopupFragment {
        this.callback = callback
        return this
    }

    ...

}
```

You can safely remove `override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface)` from `AddReminderFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using fragment's view model. You should not clear the view model by posting values to live data `postValue(T value)` as it is unnecessary.

Use the following view model,

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData().also {
            loadUsers()
            }
        }

    fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
        return users
    }

    private fun loadUsers() {
        // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
    }
}
```

In DialogFragment, initialize the view model by

```
ViewModelProviders.of(<FRAGMENTT>).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

If you are using ktx then initialize the view model by

```
// Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to this Fragment
val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()
```

Comment: That is exactly how I define and instantiate my viewmodel. I also tried first without posting value to livedata to reset, but without luck